# CiviCRM on Drupal begins Install and then reverts to "Page not Found"

Tags: drupal

The Title pretty much sums it up. 2 databases, each is correct, I'm running on a Bluehost dedicated server. It has it's own Cpanel account for static IP and SSL (eventually). But first I have to get it installed.
The installer runs for 30-40 seconds and then goes to: "The requested page "/sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php" could not be found."
Does anyone have any ideas????

Answer (score 1):

Check to be *absolutely* sure you've got CiviCRM installed to `sites/all/modules/civicrm`.

Also check that you aren't getting bounced from host A to host B, or from http to https, during the installation.

If that doesn't work, watch the PHP error log and webserver access log during the installation; that may show you what's not otherwise obvious.